# Showing a topology is connected

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, algebraic-topology, topological-groups

How would I go about showing that $ \mathbb{R} $ with the topology $ \tau = \{ \emptyset \} \cup \{ U | \pi \in U \subseteq \mathbb{R}\} $ is connected?

Preferably an explanation someone who isn't good at topology could understand. Not sure where to start with this. I understand the being connected is a topological property and that something is connected if it;s not disconnected.

A topological space is disconnected if if there exist $ U, V \in \tau $ which
are nonempty and disjoint with X = U ∪ V

Comment: Can you find two nonempty disjoint sets... at all?

Answer (score 2):

So the idea is that you want to show that if you have two open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U \cap V = \emptyset$ and $U \cup V = \mathbb{R}$, then one of either $U$ or $V$ must be the empty set.

Here's a big hint: in order for $U \cup V$ to be equal to $\mathbb{R}$, at least one of $U$ or $V$ must contain the element $\pi$ (suppose wlog that it's $U$). As $U$ and $V$ are open sets, hence in the set $\tau$, what does the property that $U \cap V = \emptyset$ mean the set $V$ must be?

Comment: Then V must be the empty set which forms a contradiction sicne U and V are non-empty by hypothesis - assuming it's disconnected? Since it can't be disconnected -> conencted.

Comment: Technically the precise way I've set up the definition of connected means you can stop at the 'hence $V$ is empty' step, but yes that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the set $\mathbb{R}$ would not be connected in this topology, the definition tells you that then you could find two nonempty, open and disjoint sets $U_1$ and $U_2$ such that $\mathbb{R} = U_1 \cup U_2$.

By the definition of what open means in your case (recall that open = set is in the topology), you should be able to get a contradiction from this. Then you have proven by contradiction that the set is connected.